Combinatorics problem. In how many ways can you arrange some colored balls given some constraint.
Given 22 balls. 7 of them are red, 7 are green and 8 are blue.In how many distinct ways can we arrange all of the balls without having a green ball right after a red ball?
Just to be clear the green ball cant be on the right of a red ball but it can be on the left.
Without the condition I know there are $$ \frac{22!}{7!\cdot8!\cdot7!} $$ to arrange them but where do I go from there..

Have you tried stars and bars ?

I have considered it but I just dont know how can you even apply it to this question..

First place all the red and blue balls in a line (15 balls). There are no restrictions on the red and blue balls. How many ways can these balls be arranged?
Next, for a fixed permutation of red and blue balls, there are 16 spots "between" these 15 balls including the left and right side. How many of these spots can a green ball be placed in? Then, how many total arrangements does that give (noting that more than 1 green ball can be placed in each spot)?
Multiply these together and that should give you the result


First create a line of $7$ reds and $8$ blues in $\binom{15}{7}$ ways
The $8$ blues create, so to say, $8$ "bins"  plus a bin left of the start of the line where greens may be accomodated,
Then applying stars and bars Th. 2,
number of valid arrangements $= \binom{15}{7}\binom{15}7$


@true blue anil: You had it right the first time! The answer really is
$
{15\choose 7}^2
$,
which evaluates to $41409225$. Explanation:
For each of the
$
15\choose 7
$
arrangements of the red and blue balls, let $x_k$ be the number of green balls immediately following the $k$-th blue ball, and let $x_0$ be the number of green balls placed before any of the red or blue balls. Then the qualifying $9$-tuples $(x_0,...,x_8)$ are just the nonnegative integer solutions to the equation
$
x_0+\cdots+x_8=7
$,
and there are
$
15\choose 7
$
such solutions.

@quasi: Thanks, that is what I was getting at when talking of the  extension of the line, but it was confusing !

@quasi : My merhod of successive permutation also works, I had made a silly error, more frequent for the past week or so with sleepless nights due to shingles ! I shall be posting it shortly,  as a variant for those who have not yet learnt stars and bars

$\underline{\textbf{Answer using successive placement}}$
This answer does not require knowledge of "stars and bars"
We shall at first successively put into place red, blue and green balls, assuming that each ball is distinct, thus
Ways to put down red and blue balls $=15!$
Ways to put down green balls taking into account that it can't come just after a red (x), so starting # of ways to put a green ball, which would normally be $16$ would be $7$ less $=9$, and increase by $1$ with each ball placed
R x R x B B R x B B B R x R x B R x B B R x$\;$ so continue from $15!$
with $15!⋅(9⋅10⋅11⋅12⋅13⋅14\cdot15)$
And arrangements erasing identity within colors
$=\dfrac{15!⋅(9⋅10⋅11⋅12⋅13⋅14\cdot15)}{7!7!8!} = 41409225$
